# Ajax HtmlEditorExtender can not change font size and font name

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I'm using the latest release of AjaxControlToolkit.
When use HTMLEditorExtender, I see it work good, but when I try change font name or font size, text not change. I don't know why but get a message from console:
`The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.`
Please tell me a solution for fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First select all the text and then try to change font size, it will work. If don’t the type some text in textbox after paste, and select all text and then change size, and at last remove text you typed.